# How do I overload Kotlin's string template operator (the dollar symbol)?

Tags: string, kotlin, operator-overloading, dollar-sign

I'm sure I've read that Kotlin's "dollar operator" for string templates can be redefined, but their [documentation on operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html) does not indicate how to overload it, and their [documentation on string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#string-templates), like most online tutorials on string templates, tell you merely how to use the dollar symbol. A search on StackOverflow likewise turned up no obvious questions that address this issue.

Is there a way to overload the Kotlin string template operator, AKA the dollar symbol?

For an example:

```
data class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
data class Stick(val p: Point, val q: Point)
console.log('${ Stick( Point(2,1) , Point(1,7) ) }')
```

The output is

```
Stick(p=Point(x=2, y=1), q=Point(x=1, y=7))
```

But I don't want that. I want

```
[ ( 2 , 1 ) ; ( 1 , 7 ) ]
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overload the `$` operator in string templates.

*However*, that simply gets the value of the object or expression; the string template them converts each object into a string by calling its [`toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/to-string.html) method.  Every object implements that method — it's defined in the [`Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/) type that every object inherits from.  (And there's also an [extension method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html) so that it works for `null` too.)

So you can simply override `toString()`; that will take effect whenever the object is used in a string template — and also everywhere else it gets converted to a string (e.g. if passed directly to [`println()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/println.html) or to a logger).

In this case, I think it'd be more flexible to provide your own `toString()` implementation for *both* of your objects, e.g.:

```
data class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int) {
    override fun toString() = "( $x , $y )"
}

data class Stick(val p: Point, val q: Point) {
    override fun toString() = "[ $p ; $q ]"
}
```

Providing your own `toString()` is one way of making your objects more generally useful.  The standard implementation that a `data class` gives you is clear and readable, but quite long-winded, so it's quite common to give your own.  (And for classes that are *not* `data class`es, the implementation inherited from `Any` is pretty cryptic — e.g. `Stick@60652518` — so overriding it is even more important!)

Generally speaking, `toString()` tends to be aimed at programmers (e.g. to be shown in logs).  So if that might differ from what you want to show to your users, then you might want to add a separate method for the latter (especially if that would need to show only part of the data, or do more processing such as translating it into the user's language).

Comment: I like your answer, but why do you say that you can't overload `$`? Aren't you overloading it by redefining `toString`, the same way that you overload `+` when you redefine `plus`?

Comment: Consider an expression like `"1" + (2 * 3)`, which is another way to evaluate an expression, convert it to a string, and join it to another string.  You can't overload the brackets, because they're only a way to tell the compiler to evaluate that expression first; the `+` does the concatenation, and converts the value into a string (by calling its `toString()`) if needed.  It's similar with string templates: the `$` or `${…}` is just a way of telling the compiler to evaluate an expression first; it's the concatenation which does the string conversion, and that doesn't use an operator. (cont)

Comment: The `+` there is another case where a value gets converted to a string, by calling its `toString()` if needed.  And that doesn't use a `$` at all.  (As mentioned in the answer, `println()` is another.)  `toString()` is the standard way to convert objects to strings; it's used all over the place, including throughout the standard library.  `$`, though, is specific to string templates.  (contd)

Comment: So while you _could_ consider `$` to be overridden by `toString()`, it's not a helpful way to think about it — not only does overriding `toString()` affect far more than `$`, but it wouldn't let you change how `$` is applied to cases such as null, where there's no object to call `toString()` on!

Answer (score 0):

Override `Stick` class's `toString()` method:

```
data class Stick(val p: Point, val q: Point) {
   override fun toString() = "[ ( ${p.x} , ${p.y} ) ; ( ${q.x} , ${q.y} ) ]"
}
```

I don't know where it appears in the documentation, though I'm sure I've seen it.

Comment: I've never seen anything saying you can override the `$` "operator". It simply calls `toString` on whatever is passed to it. You can override `toString` on specific classes, but there's no mechanism for changing `$` to do something other than calling `toString` in a String template.

Comment: I don't follow the argument. Isn't that like saying you can't override the `+` operator; it simply calls `plus` on whatever is passed to it, and there's no mechanism for changing `+` to do something other than calling `plus`?

Comment: Huh. I never thought of it that way because I didn’t think of `toString` as an operator, since it isn’t in Java. But it does seem the same as the other operators when you put it that way.

Comment: @Tenfour04 See the selected answer, which makes a pretty good argument as to why `$` is not an operator.